# Python error in go2streetview plugin

Tags: python, qgis-plugins, google-maps-api, google-street-view

We have the go2streetview plugin installed in QGIS 2.8.6 Wien and when performing a search using this plugin, the following error appeared:

An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien\Shared Plugins\go2streetview\go2streetview.py", line 548, in canvasReleaseEvent
    self.openSVDialog()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien\Shared Plugins\go2streetview\go2streetview.py", line 571, in openSVDialog
    print self.bbeUrl
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

QGIS version:
2.8.6-Wien Wien, e72e2ab

Python path: ['C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien\Shared Plugins\processing', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python', u'C:/Users/adowning/.qgis2/python', u'C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS Wien\Shared Plugins', u'C:/Users/adowning/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/QGISWI~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\bin\python27.zip', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\DLLs', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\bin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\python_dateutil-2.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2014.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win32.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\six-1.6.1-py2.7.egg', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', u'C:/Users/adowning/.qgis2//python', 'C:\PROGRA~2\QGISWI~1\apps\qgis-ltr\python\plugins\fTools\tools', '//fileserver1/Uniform/Mapping/QGIS/Projects']

This error doesn't occur all the time and so far only happened twice out of the twenty times I've tested this. Are you able to advise what the cause of this may be please?